Mapping of Utility function to a single vector
So I was watching this YouTube video and during it, he said that it is possible to create a bijection between a utility function and vector, which is then used to understand the ordinal ranking. I was wondering how this was done, as I don't think is possible according to linear algebra.
(In case you want to watch the video)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5ev-RAg7Xs&ab_channel=PhysicsfortheBirds
Since my experience with economics is limited, this question may be poorly worded and I apologize for that.
Edit: Upon thinking about it further I think the answer is that we are not mapping the utility function to a vector, but the indifference curve to a vector. And so, this mapping should be possible according to linear algebra. Am I on the right track in my thinking?

Please make your question self-contained. It should stand without watching an external video.

@MichaelGreinecker I'm sorry, I just made it self-contained.
